# Average number of steps to return to the origin of a random walk on a 2-d lattice.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, mathematical-physics, random-walk, statistical-mechanics

Suppose I have a random walker on a 2-d square lattice with periodic boundary conditions with equal probability of going in any of the four directions. The walk ends when the walker reaches the point it started from. What will be the average number of sites visited as a function of the no of steps N taken by such a walker. Can I get an easy bound on this function? Also note, this is not a self avoiding walker. Also, will the properties change if I have a 2-d triangular lattice instead?

Comment: The title and the body ask two different questions. The question in the title is clear. The body asks for "the average number of sites visited as a function of the number of steps $N$ taken". It's not clear what this might mean, since further up you say that the walk ends when the walker reaches the point it started from, so there doesn't seem to be any choice in the number $N$ of steps taken. Do you mean the conditional expectation of the number of sites visited, given that it took $N$ steps to return? In any case, the body seems to ask a different question than the title. Please clarify.